# c# DirectoryInfo on multiple hard drives

Tags: c#

I need something that will go and check like `System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"d:\");` but for every hard drive apart from C E F. I need something stable if I buy new hard drives in the future.

Comment: unclear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: You have made a statement. What is the question?

Comment: Instead of doing (@"d:\"); how do I use for example hard drive g as well?

Comment: PS when you get these new drives don't swap the cables about for the existing ones...

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what you asked but I think you can use [`Environment.GetLogicalDrives()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getlogicaldrives.aspx) method.

> Returns an array of string containing the names of the logical drives
>   on the current computer.

```
string[] drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
foreach (var drive in drives)
{
    Console.WriteLine(drive);
}
```

In my computer, output is;

```
C:\
D:\
Q:\
Y:\
Z:\
```

[image]

As an alternativly, take a look at [`DriveInfo.GetDrives`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) method.

> Retrieves the drive names of all logical drives on a computer.

Example from *MSDN* page;

```
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("  File type: {0}", d.DriveType);
        if (d.IsReady == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
            Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
            Console.WriteLine(
                "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes", 
                d.AvailableFreeSpace);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes",
                d.TotalFreeSpace);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ",
                d.TotalSize);
        }
```

You can get these informations;

```
Drive C:\
  File type: Fixed
  Volume label:
  File system: NTFS
  Available space to current user:   447202275328 bytes
  Total available space:             447202275328 bytes
  Total size of drive:               500105216000 bytes
Drive D:\
  File type: CDRom
Drive Q:\
  File type: Network
  Volume label: HDS4
  File system: NTFS
  Available space to current user:     4053897216 bytes
  Total available space:               4053897216 bytes
  Total size of drive:              1188893290496 bytes
Drive Y:\
  File type: Network
  Volume label: Data
  File system: NTFS
  Available space to current user:     5525561344 bytes
  Total available space:               5525561344 bytes
  Total size of drive:                72958230528 bytes
Drive Z:\
  File type: Network
  Volume label: HDS3
  File system: NTFS
  Available space to current user:   147224600576 bytes
  Total available space:             147224600576 bytes
  Total size of drive:              1230321479680 bytes
```

Comment: Is it possible to use (@"c:\FTP\,g:\FTP\") for example?

Comment: @IngelaTörner I don't understand. `c:\FTP` and `g:\FTP` are folders. Do you want these folders' informations for all drives? Please clarify it.

Comment: I need to be able to get directoryInfo with multiple hard drives with one statement. Apart from C,E,F.

Comment: @IngelaTörner _With one statement_? So you can write your own method which takes `params` parameter and so you can call it which return from `Environment.GetLogicalDrives()` method.

Comment: @IngelaTörner. If you want to do it in one function you write it as the gentleman suggested. Then you call that one function. Programming taking a complex operation and breaking it into simpler steps...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for

```
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
foreach (var di in drives)
{
    Console.WriteLine(di.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the drive names of all logical drives on a computer using [DriveInfo.GetDrives Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives)

This method returns an array of [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo).
Using the property [DriveInfo.DriveType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.drivetype) you can also exclude, for example, CDRoms or network drives.

Answer (score 0):

You want it one go?

```
public static IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> GetSelectedDirectoryInformation(String argDirectoryName, IEnumerable<String> argExcludeDrives)
{
   foreach(DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
   {
      if ((argExcludedDrives == null) || (!argExcludedDrives.Contains(di.Name)))
      {
         string directory = Path.Combine(di.Name,argDirectoryName); 
         if (DirectoryExists(directory))
         {
            yield return new DirectoryInfo(directory);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now in one go you can do

```
foreach(DirectoryInfo di in GetSelectedDirectoryInformation("FTP",new string[] {@"C:\",@"E:\",@"F:\"}))
{
   // Do something with it.
}
```

Comment: If someone clever comes along and does this with one lambda, I'll give them 10.